# Pass Session Data From Controller to View in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, session, controller

I want to create edit user account feature in my Laravel project, so i want to pass current session data from controller to view but i got an error **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**. Before passing data, i create login feature to get session, here is my LoginController to get session:

```
public function loginprocess(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
            return redirect()->route('index.user');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
```

Then in another controller i create this function:

```
public function account()
    {
        $data=[
            'account' => Session::get('user'),
            'titleweddinc' => "Account - User Dashboard"
        ];
        return view('user.account',$data);
    }
```

And in the view i use this code:

```
{{ $account->name }}
```

In database user i sure I make sure in the user table there is a **name** field. I try to get {{ $titleweddinc }} and it can appeat. Does anyone know what my mistake is?

Comment: Since you are new to laravel I ask why not just get the username in blade and not have to deal with the session? Something like `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` right in the blade file

Answer (score 0):

**use like this**

```
    public function account()
        {
            $data=[
                'account' => Session::get('user'),
                'titleweddinc' => "Account - User Dashboard"
            ];
            return view('user.account',compact('data'));
        }
```

**If Object then print like**

```
{{ $data->account->name}}
```

**Check if Array  then  print like**

```
{{ $data['account']['name']}}
```